# Mysql Magento consume 600%+ CPU

Tags: magento2, database

Everytime I see:

```
14267 mysql     20   0 3893204 594288  24648 S 682.4  2.0  63:48.91 mysqld
```

is CPU `682%`. I disable cron, all import/export jobs etc. After `restart mariadb`, return CPU to normall about 33%. But after few minutes again back to 300-700% consume CPU.

What is  goin on? I check and everytime is mysql query:

```
+------+----------+-----------------+----------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id   | User     | Host            | db       | Command | Time | State        | Info                                                                                                 | Progress |
+------+----------+-----------------+----------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| 1947 | mall_m24 | localhost       | NULL     | Query   |    0 | Init         | show processlist                                                                                     |    0.000 |
| 2020 | mall_m24 | localhost:34122 | mall_m24 | Query   |   36 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product |    0.000 |
| 2026 | mall_m24 | localhost:34146 | mall_m24 | Query   |   34 | Sending data | SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`, IF(a |    0.000 |
| 2033 | mall_m24 | localhost:34188 | mall_m24 | Query   |   31 | Sending data | SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`, IF(a |    0.000 |
| 2041 | mall_m24 | localhost:49270 | mall_m24 | Query   |   27 | Sending data | SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`, IF(a |    0.000 |
| 2049 | mall_m24 | localhost:49312 | mall_m24 | Query   |   22 | Sending data | SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`, IF(a |    0.000 |
| 2061 | mall_m24 | localhost:52592 | mall_m24 | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
+------+----------+-----------------+----------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

When I kill process, then again this process back. What is goin on?

** The problem is from few days. Before working everyting normall.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
for server CPU usage analysis of the 682%.

Comment: How many total cores/cpus does your server have available?  Divide the cpu% / cpu's = average total cpu busy.  From OS command prompt, iostat -xm 5 3 will reveal the count.